# Open graph story not approved when submitted for review but is posting to activity timeline

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to have my custom open graph action approved by Facebook for my iOS app but it keeps getting rejected with this error message:

> "Your Open Graph action failed to publish on any of the Platforms you
>   submitted. Make sure the action is working properly by publishing the
>   action with a test user before resubmitting."

I have posted the custom open graph story many many times to both my account (admin for the app), a real Facebook account added as a tester and the Open Graph Test User account. The only app in my settings is the iOS app.

In [this article](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process) about the submission process  it says:

> "Before submitting for review, you must publish the Open Graph story
>   from within your app with the test user. Once you have successfully
>   published your Open Graph story, you will be able to see sample
>   stories within the developer console."

I am able to post the open graph story using the test user (Open Graph Test User) but I don't see sample stories in the developer console. I do see lots of objects in the Facebook Object Browser and I do see the stories posted in the activity logs for these users.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: so did you figure it out?

Comment: Nope and Facebook was no help. I ended up pulling this functionality out of the app.

Comment: not exactly a happy ending :(